# Application does not exist in iOS simulator - Titanium Alloy

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am a newbie of Titanium. I created a Titanium Alloy project, and run it in iPhone simulator. And it builds successfully:

```
....
[INFO] :   Finished building the application in 1s 881ms
[INFO] :   Running application in iOS Simulator
[INFO] :   Launching application in iOS Simulator
[INFO] :   Focusing the iOS Simulator
[INFO] :   Application has exited from iOS Simulator
[INFO] :   Project built successfully in 2s 645ms
```

But when I open iOS simulator, the application does not exist. 
Note: I already put the link to the correct path of iOS SDK.

Can you help me figure out, how to solve this problem?

Comment: "[INFO] :   Application has exited from iOS Simulator" If you think you have a settings issue, create a new blank project and just build it.  If it runs in your simulator, then you have a problem with your project.  You'll have to start looking at it for errors.

Comment: I created a new blank project, and then build it. The iOS Simulator is still not invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following could solve your problem

1)Reset the iOS simulator

2)Delete the Old build

3)Give the project clean build

Thanks

Comment: I already did the above steps, but the iOS simulator is still not invoked. What a pity.

Comment: titanium studio 3.1.3   && iOS SDK is 5.1  ---> But I don't know if Titanium is able to automatically discover iOS SDK or not.

Comment: While in Studio Perspective, there is a small red icon in the upper left that opens a dashboard.  If you click on Getting Started, it tells you what SDKs Titanium Studio currently sees on your system.  If you don't see a green check, then IOS isn't setup.  I don't think that is your problem though.  You wouldn't be able to build the project otherwise.  I think you should uninstall and reinstall the Titanium Studio and Xcode.

Comment: I saw the green check for iOS. Moreover, I can run with Android, but not for iOS